# Ссылочные классы

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! Начал изучать С ++ совсем недавно и наткнулся на ссылочные классы. Не мог бы кто нибудь нормально объяснить данное свойство классов. По гуглив нормальной информации по поводу для чего нужны и в каких случаях применять не нашел.

Comment: Ссылочные классы? Что-то новенькое, не видел такого даже в C++11. Присоединяюсь к вопросу.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то вопрос про RValue reference, так?

Comment: Я имел ввиду такое объявление класса "public ref class"- что это означает и для чего это нужно?

Answer (score 5):

Это вообще не C++. Это C++/CLI — надстройка над C++, позволяющая использовать .NET и нативный код в одном модуле.

В случае, когда вы пишете на чистом .NET, лучше взять C#. В случае, когда у вас чисто нативное приложение, используйте чистый C++. В случае, когда вам нужно подключить к .NET-коду библиотеку на чистом C, пользуйтесь P/Invoke. C++/CLI нужен в довольно редких случаях, когда вы пишете прослойку между кодом на .NET и библиотеками на C++.

Писать большой проект на C++/CLI я бы не рекомендовал, он очень неудобен.

---

Итак, `ref class` в C++/CLI — это просто класс .NET. Классы .NET ведут себя не так, как класс C++. Есть довольно много отличий, про которые лучше всего прочитать где-нибудь в MSDN. Базовые отличия таковы:

- У классов C++ есть деструктор, который вызывается либо при выходе из диапазона видимости автоматического экземпляра класса, либо при вызове `delete`. Объекты классов .NET вручную не удаляются, их удаляет garbage collector (специальная часть .NET Framework), когда на объект более нет ссылок. (Таким образом, для объектов .NET не нужны «умные» указатели, и проблема циклических ссылок автоматически решается.)
- На экземпляр класса C++ можно получить указатель (его тип обозначается `C*`), который с некоторой натяжкой представляет собой адрес объекта в памяти. На экземпляр класса .NET можно получить лишь .NET-ссылку (её тип обозначается `C^`), по которой можно работать с объектом, но которая не является его адресом (потому что .NET-объект может свободно перемещаться в памяти.)
- В отличие от C++, .NET-классы не поддерживают множественное наследование. Однако, в .NET есть *интерфейсы* (как бы полностью абстрактные классы, с точки зрения C++), от них можно наследоваться в любом количестве.

---

Вот [список отличий побольше](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), он охватывает не только классы.

Comment: Спасибо разъяснения. Дело в том что мне нужно разобраться уже существующем проекте. Наткнувшись на это, соответственно возник вопрос: "А зачем оно вообще нужно*?". Не наткнувшись на нормальную инфу решил спросить у знающих.

Comment: @Nuri: а вы знакомы с C#? `ref class` С++/CLI — это то же, что `class` в C#.

Comment: презабавно) Очень напоминает ситуацию, когда один  чувак долго и упорно занимался изучением JavaScript, однако потом был весьма удивлен, что изучает именно JS, а не Java))

Comment: Не могли бы вы еще разъяснить что оно вообще дает, создание ссылочного класса?

Comment: @Nuri тем самым вы объявляете, что ваш тип будет ссылочным. Без данного модифыикатора это будет тип-значение. Если не знаете разницу, то гуглите по словам "value types vs reference types in .net"

Comment: @Nuri: сейчас напишу.

Comment: У меня есть небольшой опыт работы с класса в java. А java c C# схожи на сколько мне известно. Не посредственно с С# я дело не имел.

Comment: @Nuri: Угу, можете считать, что это классы Java, отличия не так существенны.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Nuri: пожалуйста!